# Actions (add, edit, delete) on form select box

Tags: jquery

I have a form, that contains almost 10-15 select boxes. Each box have some option.
There are three icons for each select box, add edit, delete.
My issue is, if I am selecting one option not able to perform edit or delete.

Can anyone help us to resolve this issue.

I am using plain html and jQuery library.

Thank You

Comment: What you want to delete. and anything you tried. also share your html

Comment: Yes, without any code who should know what you're actually doing?  Please be more elaborate...

Comment: Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/monicamandal/yjgq0x7s/

I am unable to edit and perform auto complete search

Comment: Can Anyone help me to achieve this.